# Specify alternate URL for redirect and internal lookups for Keycloak in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, spring-security, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress

So I have a spring boot application, which is deployed as a pod in Kubernetes. I also have a Keycloak server running in Kubernetes  (Same namespace). I am facing an issue with logging into my application through a browser on my local machine.

So I am specifying the `auth-server-url=http://keycloak-service-name:8080/auth`, so that my pod can access it, and it can. The problem arrises when I try to log in to my application, as it redirects to `http://keycloak-service-name:8080/auth` and this cannot be resolved locally as it is the Kubernetes service.

I also have ingress set up, so I tried specify the auth URL as the ingress `http://keycloak-ingress/auth`, but then my pod cannot access this and gets an error "Failed to load URLs from ..." as it cannot resolve the ingress domain. However, I can access the ingress from my browser.

I feel like I am missing something really obvious here, I need some kind of URL that is accessible to both the pod within the cluster, as well as outside the cluster. Or maybe there is someway to specify a seperate URL for the lookup my application is doing to "Load the URL's"?

The only way I have managed to get this to work is by exposing the service externally and using the external IP and port, but this is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that there is a frontend URL parameter in the keycloak server. I set this to point to my ingress, and set the `auth-server-url` to point to my keycloak service name. This solved my problem, in that when my application does a lookup internally it uses the service, but when I access the frontend it uses the ingress.

Comment: Could you please paste here your yaml file with ingress settings? I'm having problem accessing keycloak from browser via ingress. Thank you